# What does react docs mean by "... pass this.props.onChange directly to Chosen ..." in the article "Integrating with jQuery Chosen Plugin"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am going through the react documentation article of [integrating-with-jquery-chosen-plugin](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#integrating-with-jquery-chosen-plugin), and there they mention:

> We won’t pass this.props.onChange **directly to Chosen** because component’s props might change over time, and that includes event handlers. Instead, we will declare a handleChange() method that calls this.props.onChange, and subscribe it to the jQuery change event

This doesn't make sense to me, because they are already using(passing as prop?) `onChange` on `Chosen` in `<Chosen onChange={value => console.log(value)}>`. Here's the code the docs use just after:

```
function Example() {
  return (
    <Chosen onChange={value => console.log(value)}>
      <option>vanilla</option>
      <option>chocolate</option>
      <option>strawberry</option>
    </Chosen>
  );
}
```

It appears to me that the docs wanted to say:

> We won’t pass this.props.onChange directly to <strike>Chosen</strike> **`select`** because [Chosen]component’s props might change over time, and that includes event handlers(onChange?).

But still I don't grasp the meaning of *props including event listeners might change*. The only prop that might change here is the `children` prop, which would affect `select`'s `{this.props.children}`. Why would the `onChange` event listener change?

Can someone please elaborate upon what the docs are trying to say.

Comment: `<Chosen onChange={Math.random() < 0.5 ? value => console.log(value) : value => console.log(value)}>....`  there, prop might change.  And then -> `this.$el.off('change', this.props.onChange);` <- and then Oops.

Comment: Actually even -> `<Chosen onChange={() => console.log(value)}>..`  The prop is changing every time the parent consolidates the DOM tree, as it's an inline arrow function.  `<Chosen onChange={someFn}>...` is not changing, but then docs do say might change.  Hope that makes sense..

Comment: @Keith Regarding your first comment, in real scenarios I think onChange would be assigned a fixed function and even for whatever reason onChange gets say undefined(Math.random < 0.5 becomes false), `this.$el.off('change', undefined);` seems fine to me. But realistically why would you change `onChange`'s event handler?

Comment: Event handlers are just props, props can change for any number of reasons.  eg. You might want to assign a different onChange event based on user security etc.   Btw.  there is no `false` been assigned in my example, it's a ternary operator randomly picking two different functions.   By keeping the actual event handler locally scoped, your guaranteed to have the same function been used for jQuery's  `on` & `off` handler used during mount / un-mount.  Anyway, you asked to elaborate on what the docs say, not the reasons for or against, so hopefully it now makes more sense.

Comment: I see, you are creating two different anon functions using the ternary operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what docs suggests:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.$el = $(this.el);
  this.$el.chosen();

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.$el.on('change', this.handleChange);
}

handleChange(e) {
  this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
}
```

by mentioning

> We won’t pass this.props.onChange directly to Chosen because component’s props might change over time, and that includes event handlers. Instead, we will declare a handleChange() method that calls this.props.onChange, and subscribe it to the jQuery change event

They want to avoid doing this :

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.$el = $(this.el);
  this.$el.chosen();

  this.$el.on('change', this.props.onChange);
}
```

in this example, when the component is mounted, the event listener is set and **this version of `this.props.onChange`** given as event handler is stuck, it will not be updated, but

> component’s props might change over time

there is a good example in the comments section.

so what we want is to always get the newest updated props, here's the benefit of creating our own function so we can bind it to `this`:

```js
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.$el.on('change', this.handleChange);
```

By using `this.handleChange.bind(this)` and referencing `this.handleChange` as the event handler, you ensure that the event handler alwayz calls `this.handleChange` associated with the props at the time of binding.

Comment: Thank you, very good explanation. It is about getting a live binding of `this.props.onChange`. I tested a simple js version of it https://jsfiddle.net/ym69Lqdz/